# Is this password protected download script secure?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, security

I developed an upload script which has the possebility to set up a password.
Now i want to know, how secure is it against users who are looking into the sourcecode?

My way of thinking was to put the file for download in a folder with a long name. This foldername is a md5 hash which is the former password.

like: http://www.examlpe.com/098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6/my_file.zip

Now, the user can type a password on my website into an input field and a jquery script makes a md5 hash from it.

My foldername md5 hash comes from a mysql database.

Now i make another md5 hash from both md5 hashes ("user input hash" and "database hash") and compare both. If they're equal, the script shows the path to the protected file for downloading, using the jquery md5 hash from the user input.

```
window.jQuery.("#my_id").click(function() {
var inputPassword = //input value of password field "e.g.: test";
Password = md5(inputPassword); //is 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
md5_Password = md5(Password) //is fb469d7ef430b0baf0cab6c436e70375

//Compare#####
if (md5_Password == 'fb469d7ef430b0baf0cab6c436e70375') //hash from the mysql database
{
  //show the Link 
  //http://www.examlpe.com/ + Password + /my_file.zip
}

});
```

I know, if somebody knows the foldername, he is able to get the file but this is not for real secret stuff. It should only protect the file for a (sourcecode looking) user from downloading it.

Comment: If this is all done client-side, then it's not secure in the slightest. I can just view the source, get the URL then type it in to my browser.

Comment: I'd place the files outside the public area and use a header to download the file and hide its location.

Comment: all of the above. Plus MD5 is not hard to crack by brute force these day, even if the source code wasn't already visible to anyone who wants to look. Client-side code is never secure. Do something in PHP if it involves security.

Comment: No amount of tinkering can make a Javascript password check ever even slightly secure. Forget it. Perhaps some of the code is really PHP?

Comment: But the only md5 hash, you can see in the source-code is: fb469d7ef430b0baf0cab6c436e70375. But the path is made from 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 which is not published in the source exept the user typed in the correct password.

Comment: So? That gives me access to the document even if I don't know the hand-written password. I can just pick that from the code and append it to the URL. I can completely bypass your code.

Comment: Also, even if you did this exact same thing server-side, security by obscurity is not security at all. As Funk said, store the documents in a non web-accessible location (i.e there is no URL to the file, however obscured). Then just have one "download.php" script which accepts the password and document ID in the postback. If the password is ok, fetch the file content from the disk and offer it for download, if not return an error. Then no-one can ever guess the document URL and bypass the security

Comment: No, only if you know that "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6" is the md5 hash from the hand-written password "test" and "fb469d7ef430b0baf0cab6c436e70375" is the md5 hash from " 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6" cause this is the only thing, which is seen in the sourcecode.

Comment: Double MD5 hashing isn't more secure than a single MD5 hash either..

Comment: @ADyson: But this part of code is only shown if you have the password and this is made from your input. Maybe i miss some point but i don't get it, you know?

Comment: It's still only security by obscurity. Once someone has the final document link, they can share it wherever they like.  Once one person gets the password and the link, it's no longer secure. Anyone can type it directly into their browser and get the document, bypassing this password page. The security should be on the URL to the document itself, not on this page, which is merely used to hide the real URL. That's why you should follow the solution Funk and I outlined, regardless of any of this stuff about hashing

Comment: Just to make another point on your hashing. It's litterly 0 cost to PHP to md5. If you're bruteforcing you will also apply the same tactic to cracking as it's almost no difference in cost. See [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/AWlIa) for proof of time between a double md5() and 10 md5()

Comment: Okay, now i got it. Yes, i know that if somebody knows the link, it can be shared. But if you don't know it, how could you get it from my sourcecode? You can't decrypt the md5 hash, can you? You can't list the directory if the webserver is secure.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript: The double md5 is only for not publishing the real path to the file in the sourcecode.

Comment: I think isThisJavascript's point is that someone could try to brute force the server itself by guessing passwords and generating MD5s. Especially since your code gives away the fact you're using mD5 in the first place - don't give away clues about how your security works! But again it's all completely pointless because the document URL itself is not secure. I agree it's hard to get the first MD5 from the source code, but it's featherweight protection at best

Comment: @ADyson: okay, that is an answer i can live with. Yes you can brute force the password itself but you can not easily get the first md5 hash which comes out of the mysql database and can not easily get the document URL itself. Only if the link is shared and then you could change the password.

Comment: It's not so much you could _change_ the password if the link is shared, merely that the password becomes _unnecessary_ in order to access the document. Bear in mind too that if this is on the public internet, search engines can potentially index your documents. Again, if you actually truly care about the security of your documents, you simply must ditch this solution entirely and go with the alternative approach we described. Paun's answer is a very basic start to that solution.

Comment: @mcroll looking at the source code alone won't give you access to the files but would make very clear how to approach an attack. After that with enough time one could find valid URLs and access the files. Also how do you protect against common passwords or users who use the same password? The URLs would also be saved by browsers, proxies so on. I'd recommend you consider a more server-side approach.

Comment: Thanks for your advises. I think i'll "ditch my solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my projects I usually use some sort of middleman PHP file reader and redirect all legitimate resource download requests to it. Basic sample looks something like:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["file"];
//check if user is allowed to access the file using your app logic
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

obfuscation is always good, but never one should protect resources only in client.

EDIT:
Sorry for the short answer, it only shows how to serve the resource content via a proxy like script. In authorization process one could be using sessions or if it's a cross-domain request authorization tokens should be sent something like 'Authorization', 'Bearer MY-SECRET-TOKEN' and be validated on server. I employ JWT for a resource library on a university website.

Exact answer to the question: No, the script is not secure.

Comment: Why do I have a feeling this is vulnerable to LFI exploit

Comment: this doesn't include any actual security, it should be noted. Password check should also be implemented here. And the file should be stored in an offline location. And probably the GET parameter should be a document ID which is looked up in a database to get the real file path, so that duplicates / multiple folders etc can be accounted for. And so people can't go sniffing for filenames. But yeah it's a start of a solution.